# Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
function convert_realsoft($type, $input_id) {
  $dial_arr = array();

  switch ($type) {
    case 'action':
      $dial_arr = array(
        'lorem'       => 1,
        'ipsum'       => 2,
        'dolor'       => 3,
      );

      return $dial_arr[$input_id];

    break;

    case 'desk':
      $dial_arr = array(
        'sit'  => 1,
        'amet' => 2,
      );

      return $dial_arr[$input_id];

    break;

    ...and next case...
  }
}
```

**This function returns me:**
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in...

Problem is in line return. After delete this line, warning disappear...

I tested several options. Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Which line exactly does this occur?

Comment: Side note, there is no need to place the same `return` statement in every case, instead just put it at the end of the function.

Comment: make sure the $input_id is valid (i.e one of ipsum, lorem, etc.)

Comment: Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in drupal_render() (line 5859 in /data/d/i/site.com/web/includes/common.inc).

But this is file in cms. No my file...

Comment: Can you post the code on that line?

Answer (score 1):

i think this should be like this :-

```
function convert_realsoft($type, $input_id) {
  $dial_arr = array();

  switch ($type) {
    case 'action':
      $dial_arr[$input_id] = array(
        'lorem'       => 1,
        'ipsum'       => 2,
        'dolor'       => 3,
      );

      return $dial_arr[$input_id];

    break;

    case 'desk':
      $dial_arr[$input_id] = array(
        'sit'  => 1,
        'amet' => 2,
      );

      return $dial_arr[$input_id];

    break;

    ...and next case...
  }
}
```

Comment: Why then not just `return array('lorem' => 1, ..)`, and why then has the function an $input_id?

Comment: i just saw a problem that used index for an array in return statement which wasn't initilized or existed.I am not the one who asked this question.please ask this to the relavent person...

Comment: That will give an `Notice: Undefined offset: -- value of $input_id --`. The warning he is seeing is one of the kind `$a = 1; $a['test']; // $a is not an array`

Comment: $input_id is one of the value in array. lorem, ipsum or dolor.
I want return the number of this value.

Comment: @user3078306 in that case there is no need of $input_id in function parameter as well as in relavent code return whole array use outside by its index value ..

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly passing into the function for the `$input_id` parameter when you make the function call? Is it an integer or string?  Can you post a sample function call?

My guess is that you are attempting to use an integer value to find the value in an array, yet your array needs a key to get the value based on how you are creating the array's in the function.

Also, I would write your return statement like this (I spoke of this in a previous comment)

```
function convert_realsoft($type, $input_id) {

  $dial_arr = array();

  switch ($type) {

    case 'action':

      $dial_arr = array(
        'lorem'       => 1,
        'ipsum'       => 2,
        'dolor'       => 3,
      );

    break;

    case 'desk':

      $dial_arr = array(
        'sit'  => 1,
        'amet' => 2,
      );

    break;

    //...and next case...
  }

  return $dial_arr[$input_id];

}
```

Comment: convert_realsoft('action', get_select_ids($node_arr, 'field_object_type'))

Comment: function get_select_ids($type_arr, $field_name) {
  $get_select_ids = field_get_items('node', $type_arr, $field_name);

  return $get_select_ids[0]['value'];
}

Comment: Thanks for posting the other code, I've updated your original post to include that.  Try to be more descriptive in the future, it will help others help you faster. :)

Comment: So, now that I've seen your other code, what is the function `get_select_ids` returning, is it an integer or a string?  You need to answer this question to help us figure out what the problem is.

Comment: get_select_ids returning string.

Comment: If it is returning a string, that is good, have you verified that in all of your cases, that the value of the string being passed in for $input_id, is in fact one of the keys for the array that is created for the respective $type in the convert_realsoft function?